# How do I check if user is not allowed to change password via Terminal

Tags: terminal, catalina

How do I check if the user cannot change password via Terminal? I know you can do `pwpolicy -u username -getpolicy` and look for `canModifyPasswordforSelf=0` but I can't use pwpolicy for this. Any ideas?